# Auto-Pagination or something similar

Tags: javascript, php, pagination

I'm fairly new to css, html, php, javascript etc, but I'm slowly but surely building a small blog site with the help of stackoverflow. Keep in mind I have only been coding for about 5 months.

What I'm looking for is some help with pagination, I've searched but I need someone to point me in the definite direction with my search or at least help me out a bit.

I want to "auto-paginate" my pages, so example; if I wanted 15 blog posts per page, on each page how do I automatically do this with pagination, php etc. I know I can manually do it but as I add more blog posts it becomes quite tedious over time, so I was looking for a way to "automatically do it" if there is a way..

Thanks in advance to everyone who understands and is willing to help!

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free coding or code conversion or tutorial or library finding service** You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: Clarke, you still can comment or accept the answer to your question (even if it's "on hold").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do pagination with `$_SESSION`, this is what you need :

- The posts themselves (or their ids).
- How many posts to display per page.
- What is the current post on screen.

For example, if you have 100 posts (from 0 to 99), you want to display 10 posts per page, and the current post is 60, then you will have to display posts from 60 to 69. These three vital pieces of data can be stored in `$_SESSION` variables :

- `$_SESSION[ "posts" ]`.
- `$_SESSION[ "per_page" ]`.
- `$_SESSION[ "current" ]`.

You have to use `$_SESSION` because `$_SESSION` data persists after page refresh.

Next is an example without a database, so the "posts" are stored in an array. In order to test it, copy-paste next code in a file, save the file as .PHP and open it in your browser :

```
<?php
session_start(); // NECESSARY TO USE $_SESSION.

// SAMPLE DATA.
$_SESSION[ "posts" ] = array( "aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee","fff","ggg",
                              "hhh","iii","jjj","kkk","lll","mmm","nnn" );
$_SESSION[ "per_page" ] = 4; // PAGES PER PAGE.
if ( ! isset( $_SESSION[ "current" ] ) ) // IF THIS IS THE FIRST PAGE
   $_SESSION[ "current" ] = 0; // CURRENT BLOG.

if ( isset( $_POST[ "submit" ] ) ) // IF "PREVIOUS" OR "NEXT" WERE PRESSED
   { if ( ( $_POST[ "submit" ] == "Previous page" ) &&
          ( ( $_SESSION[ "current" ] - $_SESSION[ "per_page" ] ) >= 0 ) )
            $_SESSION[ "current" ] -= $_SESSION[ "per_page" ];
     if ( ( $_POST[ "submit" ] == "Next page" ) &&
          ( ( $_SESSION[ "current" ] + $_SESSION[ "per_page" ] ) <
             count( $_SESSION[ "posts" ] ) ) )
           $_SESSION[ "current" ] += $_SESSION[ "per_page" ];
   }
?>
<html>
  <body>
    Showing posts :
    <br/>
<?php
// DISPLAY ONE PAGE OF POSTS (FROM CURRENT TO CURRENT + PER_PAGE - 1).
for ( $i = $_SESSION[ "current" ];
      $i < ( $_SESSION[ "current"  ] + $_SESSION[ "per_page" ] ); $i++ )
  if ( isset ( $_SESSION[ "posts" ][ $i ] ) ) // IN CASE LAST PAGE IS ODD
     echo $_SESSION[ "posts" ][ $i ] . "<br/>";
?>
    <br/>
    <form method="post">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Previous page"/>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next page"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

To make this work with your already made blog site, get the ids of your posts and store them in the array, and, in the HTML section, use those ids to get the posts' data from database and display it on screen.

Comment: I don't quite understand as yet but thank you for taking the time to respond and explain,and thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I will test the code out and do some more research.

Once, again I'm fairly new to coding so thanks for bearing with me!

Comment: @A.Clarke, if you still have trouble just post a new question anytime.

Comment: Okay I did exactly what was told, now I have a couple more questions


Ques 1)When you say "ids of my posts" you mean the titles right? For example if a title was called "my first blog post" would that be the id of the post? 

Ques 2) Also I see the prev and next buttons, but what if I wanted [prev] [1][2][3][4]...[204][next] if I wanted buttons to display like that how would I go about doing that?

Ques 3) And last question, I can still use CSS to make the pagination look exactly how I want it to right?

Comment: @A.Clarke : 1) If your posts are stored in a database table, possibly each row (each post) will have an ID column to uniquely identify it, so, store those IDs in the array, later you can do "select * from tbl_posts where id='$id`" to get the post's data. 2) Display the numbers from "current" to "current + per_page" (for next button), and from "current" to "current - per_page" (for prev button). 3) Yes, you can use as much CSS as you want.

Comment: I dont have a database table, I'm still a beginner but I managed to finish the website with pure html5, css, javascript(for a slider and back to top button) and php(for includes) but now I just need the help with pagination but thank you I will look into how to set up a database table, because I'm still very new to this and learning as I go.

Comment: @A.Clarke, you don't need a database. Actually, you can store the whole posts in the array, or in a text file. My code is just the "pagination engine".

Comment: How would I go about setting up the text file, and every time I add a new blog post I would have to update the text file right? And also if I have a search feature on my site, would the pagination automatically paginate the returned results as well or I'd have write a totally different code for that?

Comment: My code works for an array of data, any array of data. If you fill the array with the text file, it will work, and, if you fill the array with searched data, it will work too.